# Azure Data Factory Data Flow Joins condition Duplicate Records

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am doing data transformation using data flow component in ADF. My source data is parquet file to read the data and applying the join component to fetch the result. I am getting duplicated record while I do the left outer join. How do we handle this issues? I am also doing sink operation to use cache the records (not doing any write adls or DB).

my sequence of the data flow diagram:

[image]

[image]

[image]

inner join :
[image]

Comment: Can you provide sample data/data preview of the inner join and component C?

Comment: i have edited and shared inner join details

Answer (score 0):

- You get duplicate records when either your have duplicates on the left stream of the left outer join transformation or there is an issue with your join condition.
- The following is a case where an incorrect condition resulted in duplicate records in the output. The following is my source1:

[image]

- The following is the data of my source2:

[image]

- When I apply the join condition as `source1.id != source2.id`, it generates duplicate records. The following is an output image of the same. So, re-check the left stream for duplicates and also validate your join condition again.

[image]

Comment: I am applyied ource1.id == source2.id this condition

Comment: how to avoid this issues

Comment: I have validated, there is no other solution with me, I am expecting from you or some one help us but i did now aggregate activity to apply one of the column made group by after that i did not see duplicate, this is right way to implement ?, please advice..

Comment: Yes, use group by and count and then filter values with count>1. If any records are returned, then that indicates that there are no duplicates. If there are no duplicates, then duplicates should not be showing up.